# Target lock/release on XBox 360 controller

Tags: pc, controllers, dark-souls-3

I just started playing Dark Souls 3 on PC. I get it's meant to be played on gamepad, so I grabbed my X360.

But I can't figure out which button is used for target lock/release. It says R, with an arrow above it pointing down. I tried RB and RT but obviously it's not it. So which button shouls I use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the other R button: clicking the right control stick into the controller.

Comment: No, it's different. There's the right stick, represented by `R`, which controls the camera. And there's this `R, with an arrow above it pointing down`, which should control target lock/release.

Comment: There's also `L` which is the left stick, used to walk, and there's the `L, with an arrow above it pointing down` which is used to "while dashing, use to jump". To dash, I use `L` and hold `B`. If I just press `B` he "evades", if I hold it he dashes/runs. So, if I press `L, with an arrow above it pointing down` while using `L` to walk and hold `B` to dash, he'll jump.

Comment: That symbol "R with an arrow above it pointing down"  indicates pushing the stick into the controller until it clicks, not moving it in any direction.

Comment: Similar to R3 and L3 on playstation.